# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php

Hola bueno tengo el siguiente problema, me he informado en preguntas iguales a esta pero no he podido solucionar el problema. Cabe decir que estoy cursando mis estudios aun por lo cual no estoy tan experimentado en esto del php y la programación en general.

Problema

```
file_get_contents(http://localhost:3000/Api/Productos/Api-Productos.php?Categoria=Procesadores): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Código **Catalogo.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> TryCatch™  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/test1.css"/>
<body>
  <div id="Contenedor">
    <header> <h1> Catalogo </h1> </header>
    <?php include_once('Layout/menu.php'); ?>
    <main>  
      <?php
      $response = file_get_contents('http://localhost:3000/Api/Productos/Api-Productos.php?Categoria=Procesadores');
      echo ($response);
      ?>
    </main>    
    <?php include_once('Layout/footer.php'); ?>
</body>   
</html>
```

Y el codigo del **/Api/Productos/Api-Productos.php** es

```
include_once ('productos.php');
if(isset($_GET['Categoria'])){
    $Categoria = $_GET['Categoria'];
    if($Categoria == ''){
        echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 400, 'response' => 'No existe esa categoria']);
    } else {
        $productos = new Productos();
        $items = $productos->getItemsByCategory($Categoria);
        echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 200, 'items' => $items]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 400, 'response' => 'No hay accion']);
}
```

A lo cual en mi "Catalogo.php" que es el primer codigo que muestro deberia mostrarme los valores obtenidos de *http://localhost:3000/Api/Productos/Api-Productos.php?Categoria=Procesadores*, los cuales son los siguientes:

```
{"statuscode":200,"items":[{"id":"4","Nombre":"5 5600x","Valor":"399000","Imagen":"R5.jpg","Categoria":"Procesadores"},{"id":"5","Nombre":"Ryzen 7 5800x","Valor":"449999","Imagen":"R7.jpg","Categoria":"Procesadores"},{"id":"6","Nombre":"9 5900x","Valor":"895000","Imagen":"R9.jpg","Categoria":"Procesadores"}]}.
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios

Comment: Hay varias causas para obtener ese error, por ejemplo: 1- Que la URL no sea correcta, 2- La directiva `allow_url_fopen` no esté activada en _php.ini_ y, de ser el caso, debes activarla o, en su defecto, hacer la petición con [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)

Comment: Lo primero que te recomiendo es para conocer realmente lo que tenes activo en PHP, crea un archivo algo.php vacío y colócale `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Al abrirlo podrás ver todo lo vinculado versión de php, funciones, modules y mas.

Comment: Si tengo activado el `allow_url_fopen` y el `allow_url_include`. Por ejemplo si e cambio el url por un video de YouTube me redirige a la pagina de YouTube pero no con la url que necesito